# Loop over Session Collection variable in ASPX page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

For an assignment I have to create a shopping cart, each item is added as an Object to a Session variable called "ShoppingCart"

Example:

```
'Created elsewhere eg. Home.aspx.vb'
Session("ShoppingCart") = New Collection

'On a Product Page, Product is a Class that holds the product name/price'
Dim product As New Product
product.SetName("Cheese")
Session("ShoppingCart").add(product)
```

I now have to display the contents of the Session varibale on a "Checkout" page so the user can see all their items. Is it possible to loop over the Collection on the `.aspx` page or is there a better method to dynamically display the contents of the Session variable?

I'm thinking it may be better to build the output on the server as I would need to access each objects name to display it.

Example of Ideal output:

```
<html>
  <header>
  </header>
  <body>
      <table>
          <tr>
          <td>Cheese</td>
          <td>x1</td>
          <td><button>Remove</button></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the type of object stored in Session("ShoppingCart")? Presumably it's a list of Products, if so, loop through the list or databind the list for example in GridView- or Repeater-control.

Comment: @Esko yes its a `Collection`, but how exactly do I loop through it and whats the best way to loop over a Collection of objects and return their details in suitable way, should I do it server side or is it doable from the .aspx page?

Comment: Server side of course, you can not access the session in client side anyway (without ajax). So go read about databinding for gridview or repeater-controls.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is WebForms, you can bind the products to a Repeater or to a DataList.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptProducts" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblProductName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ProductName")%>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

And bind to it from code behind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim products As Collection = DirectCast(Session("ShoppingCart"), Collection)

        rptProducts.DataSource = products
        rptProducts.DataBind()

    End Sub
```

Comment: Im sure it works, however I'm getting an error `The server tag is not well formed` referring to `<asp:Label ID="lblProductName" runat="server" Text="<%#Eval("ProductName")%>" />`

Comment: Try using a single quote for the Text property. <asp:Label ID="lblProductName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ProductName")%>' />

I just edited the answer to use single quotes. I just tested on my end and that's what it was.

Comment: @AriVictor Did that last change resolve the error for you? If so, can you mark the answer as accepted?